How to solve $f(t)=\int_{0}^{t}\tau e^{3\tau} \sin(t−\tau) \text{d}\tau$
How to solve this using convolution theorem? I already tried it but my answer is nowhere the choices given in the sheet. I got $\frac{-1}{[(s-13)^2((s-3)^2+1)]}$.

Applying inverse Laplace transform is left?

For the question in title, are you obliged to use the convolution theorem ?

Given Integral
$$f(t) = \int \tau e^{3\tau} \sin(t - \tau) d\tau$$

Laplace Transforms:

For $ g(\tau) = \tau e^{3\tau} $:
Using the known Laplace transform formula:
$$ \mathcal{L}\{\tau e^{a\tau}\} = \frac{1}{(s - a)^2} $$
Thus:
$$\mathcal{L}\{\tau e^{3\tau}\} = \frac{1}{(s - 3)^2}$$

For $ h(t - \tau) = \sin(t - \tau) $:
Using the known Laplace transform formula for $\sin(bt)$:
$$ \mathcal{L}\{\sin(bt)\} = \frac{b}{s^2 + b^2} $$
Thus:
$$ \mathcal{L}\{\sin(t)\} = \frac{1}{s^2 + 1} $$


Therefore, we have:
$$ \mathcal{L}\{g(\tau)\} = \frac{1}{(s - 3)^2} $$
$$ \mathcal{L}\{h(t)\} = \frac{1}{s^2 + 1} $$

Convolution in the Frequency Domain:
The Laplace transform of the convolution is the product of the individual Laplace transforms:
$$ \mathcal{L}\{f(t)\} = \frac{1}{(s - 3)^2 (s^2 + 1)} $$

Partial Fraction Decomposition:
To decompose:
$$ \frac{1}{(s - 3)^2 (s^2 + 1)} $$
into:
$$ \frac{3s + 4}{50 (s^2 + 1)} - \frac{3}{50 (s - 3)} + \frac{1}{10 (s - 3)^2}$$

Inverse Laplace Transforms:

For $\frac{3s + 4}{50 (s^2 + 1)} $:
$$
 \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left\{ \frac{3s}{50 (s^2 + 1)} \right\} = \frac{3}{50} \cos(t)
 $$
$$
 \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left\{ \frac{4}{50 (s^2 + 1)} \right\} = \frac{4}{50} \sin(t)
 $$
Combining these:
$$
 \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left\{ \frac{3s + 4}{50 (s^2 + 1)} \right\} = \frac{3}{50} \cos(t) + \frac{4}{50} \sin(t)
 $$

For $ -\frac{3}{50 (s - 3)} $:
$$
 \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left\{ -\frac{3}{50 (s - 3)} \right\} = -\frac{3}{50} e^{3t}
 $$

For $ \frac{1}{10 (s - 3)^2} $:
$$
 \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left\{ \frac{1}{10 (s - 3)^2} \right\} = \frac{1}{10} t e^{3t}
 $$



Combining All Terms:
$$f(t) = \frac{1}{10} t e^{3t} - \frac{3}{50} e^{3t} + \frac{3}{50} \cos(t) + \frac{4}{50} \sin(t)$$

Simplifying:
$$f(t) = \frac{1}{50} \left(e^{3 t} (5 t - 3) + 4 \sin (t) + 3 \cos (t)\right) $$



Edit: Correction in partial fraction decompression


You are wrong!
$$f(t)=\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left\frac{1}{\left(s^2+1\right) (s-3)^2}\right=\frac{1}{50} \left(e^{3 t} (5 t-3)+4 \sin (t)+3 \cos (t)\right)$$

@gpmath could you please point out where i went wrong.

Your partial fraction decomposition is wrong.

$$\frac{1}{\left(s^2+1\right) (s-3)^2}=\frac{3 s+4}{50 \left(s^2+1\right)}-\frac{3}{50 (s-3)}+\frac{1}{10 (s-3)^2}$$

Edited accordingly. Thanks
